# Django confirm email. Change value from false to true

Tags: django, django-views, django-email

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my form:

```
from django import forms

class MeetingForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = forms.DateTimeField()
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_email = forms.EmailField()
```

How to create a view that send a mail to user with link and when user clicks on this link confrimed field will change value to true?

Link is my biggest problem.

Comment: Have you seen [sites built-in framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.get_current_site)? You can grab current domain, but you have to set up it in database, for example with appropriate fixture.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

Model

```
import random
import string

class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        On save generate key which will be sent in email
        '''
        self.key = ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(32))
        super(Meeting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
```

views.py

```
def confirm(request, key):
    try:
        meeting = Meeting.objects.get(key=key)
    except Meeting.DoesNotExist:
        # wrong key, do something, redirect to somewhere etc
        template = 'error.html'
    else:
        meeting.confirmed = True
        meeting.save()
        template = 'success.html'
    render(request, template)

def send_email(request):
    email = request.user.email
    meeting = Meeting.objects.get(...your condition here...)
    send_mail('Confirmation email',
              # this is a link you wanted to
              '<a href="%s">confirm</a>' % reverse('user_confirm',
                                                   kwargs={'key': meeting.key}),
              'from@youremail.com', [email])
    render(request, 'mailsent.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^confirm/(?P<key>[\w]{32})/$', 'yourapp.views.confirm',
        name='user_confirm'),
    )
```